# String.replace "\\" with "/"

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace, escaping

There seem to be a lot of questions around this but none of the ones I found seemed to work for me.

My code:

```
string subFolderName = category = "Parent/Sub\\Sub sub";
string category = subFolderName.Replace(@"\\", @"/");
```

This returns `category` as the same string as `subFoldername`, ie:

```
"Parent/Sub\\Sub sub".
```

What I actually want is:

```
"Parent/Sub/Sub sub"
```

Comment: `"Parent/Sub\\Sub sub"` (without the leading `@`) contains a *single* \ character. So the replace doesn't find it. You're then inspecting the result in the debugger, which displays strings as you would need to have them as regular literals (e.g. it escapes the \ character)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try

```
string category = subFolderName.Replace(@"\", @"/");
```

It will  work, because `category = "Parent/Sub\\Sub sub";` contains a single `\`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I'll accept this answer as soon as SO allows.

Comment: You can replace `@"/"` with `"/"` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) said in his *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417120/string-replace-with/16417166?noredirect=1#comment23539039_16417120)*, when you write `"Parent/Sub\\Sub sub"` as a string, actually it contains only one `\` character. So, [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method can't find `\\` in your string.

When you use *[verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*, your string will be **exactly** how you wrote it.

```
string subFolderName = category = @"Parent/Sub\\Sub sub";
string category = subFolderName.Replace(@"\\", @"/");
Console.WriteLine(category);
```

Outpuw will be;

```
Parent/Sub/Sub sub
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/xmMEsv).

Answer (score 1):

How are you looking at the contents of category?  If you are using the VS debugger then it will escape the string so `\` in the string will appear as `\\`

so you either need

```
string category = subFolderName.Replace(@"\", @"/");
```

or

```
string category = subFolderName.Replace("\\", "/");
```

Comment: I was looking in the VS debugger. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

```
string category = subFolderName.Replace(@"\", "/");
```

Use this.